# What's the order of the array generated by Verilog? Syntax

Tags: fpga, verilog, programming, intel-fpga, programmable-logic

What is the correct interpretation between these two lines:

wire[2:0] w = SW[17:15] = {SW[17], SW[16], SW[15]}

wire[2:0] w = SW[17:15] = {SW[15], SW[16], SW[17]}

When I call w[0] will I get SW[15] or SW[17]? This is causing me a lot of confusion when dealing with circuits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct interpretation is

```
w[2] = SW[17]
w[1] = SW[16]
w[0] = SW[15]
```

It is simple, you are defining the endpoints of a sequence.  It then builds the sequence internally and assigns them one for one.

```
w[2:0]    is the same as {w[2],   w[1],   w[0]}
w[0:2]    is the same as {w[0],   w[1],   w[2]}
SW[13:10] is the same as {SW[13], SW[12], SW[11], SW[10]}
SW[4:7]   is the same as {SW[4],  SW[5],  SW[6], SW[7]}
```

Comment: and forthe cases where the bounds are defined like this [0:x]?